# How to get latest/top record from multiple similiar records using hibernate query methods

Tags: java, hibernate

I have below table in my MS SQL 2008

**MyTable**

```
----------------------
ID int (identity), 
action varchar(20),
uri int,
pid int,
url varchar(20),
lastpubdate date,
flag varchar(20)
```

And below are few sample records from the table:

```
ID      action      uri     pid     url                 lastpubdate         flag
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       ADD         123     233     /en/index.aspx      15 JAN 2013:09:44   NULL
2       UPD         123     233     /en/index.aspx      15 JAN 2013:10:00   NULL
3       UPD         123     233     /en/index.aspx      15 JAN 2013:10:15   NULL
4       DEL         123     233     /en/index.aspx      15 JAN 2013:10:17   NULL
```

Now I want to write method which will return one record back using hibernate query on the basis of above table on the basis of `uri` and `pid` given to method, so it goes as below:

```
public MyTable findByLastPubDate(String uri,int pid)
{
    log.info("Entering Method: MyTable.findByLastPubDate");
    StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    queryBuilder.append("select top 1 from MyTable pa where pa.publication_id = :pid and  pa.uri = :uri and pa.flag IS NULL order by pa.last_published_date DESC");

    Map<String, Object> queryParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    queryParams.put("publication_id", pid);
    queryParams.put("tcmUri", uri);

    log.debug("findByLastPubDate -> queryBuilder- "+ queryBuilder.toString());        
    return executeQuerySingleResult(queryBuilder.toString(), queryParams);
}
```

Please suggest whether above method is correct or need some modifications

**Edit:**
I want to implement below query in Hibernate

```
SELECT 
 pa.[ID]
      ,pa.[ACTION]
      ,pa.[PUBLICATION_ID]
      ,pa.[ITEM_REFERENCE_ID]
      ,pa.[ITEM_TYPE]
      ,pa.[LAST_PUBLISHED_DATE]
      ,pa.[URL]
      ,pa.[SCHEMA_ID]
      ,pa.[flag]
FROM [mytable] a
WHERE pa.ID IN
(SELECT TOP 1 b.id FROM [mytable] b WHERE b.[ITEM_REFERENCE_ID] = 342349 and
b.[PUBLICATION_ID] = 233
ORDER BY b.[LAST_PUBLISHED_DATE] DESC)
```

**Modified Method:**

```
public PublishAction findbyLatestPublishedDate(int tcmURI,int pubID) throws StorageException
    {
        log.info("Entering Method: JPAPublishActionDAO.PublishAction.findbyLatestPublishedDate");
        StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        queryBuilder.append("select pa from PublishAction pa where pa.id in(select pb.id from PublishAction pb where pb.tcmUri = :tcmURI and pb.publication_id = :pubID and rownum <= 1 order by pb.last_published_date desc)");

        Map<String, Object> queryParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        queryParams.put("publication_id", pubID);
        queryParams.put("tcmUri", tcmURI);

        log.debug("JPAPublishActionDAO findbyLatestPublishedDate -> queryBuilder- "+ queryBuilder.toString());        
        return executeQuerySingleResult(queryBuilder.toString(), queryParams);
    }
```

Comment: No it is not working throwing error in query

Comment: Please edit the question and post the error with stacktrace.

Comment: Hi Abhinav, I have added sample sql query in my question which I want to implement using hibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about your table structure, however you would need to make double call to database.

```
public PublishAction getLatestRecordonBasedID(int tcmURI,int pubID) throws StorageException
{
    StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    queryBuilder.append("from PublishAction pb where pb.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID = :tcmURI and pb.PUBLICATION_ID = :pubID order by pb.LAST_PUBLISHED_DATE desc");

    Map<String, Object> queryParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();   
    queryParams.put("tcmURI", tcmURI);
    queryParams.put("pubID", pubID);

    final List<PublishAction> myActions = executeQueryListResult(queryBuilder.toString(), queryParams, 1);

    if (myActions != null && !myActions.isEmpty()) 
    {
        StringBuilder queryBuilderFinal = new StringBuilder();
        queryBuilderFinal.append("select pa from PublishAction pa where pa.id=:myId");

        Map<String, Object> queryParamsFinal = new HashMap<String, Object>();   
        queryParamsFinal.put("myId", myActions.get(0).getId()); 
        return executeQuerySingleResult(queryBuilderFinal.toString(), queryParamsFinal);
    }
    else 
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can try something like above got solution after googling little.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `rownum` clause of hibernate and get only one result from the top once you apply an `order by`

```
select <entity.columns_list> 
from Entity entity 
where < where_condition > AND rownum <= 1
```

or in your case

```
select pa from MyTable pa 
where pa.publication_id = :pid and  pa.uri = :uri 
and pa.flag IS NULL and rownum <=1
order by pa.last_published_date DESC
```

### EDIT:

```
select pa from [mytable] pa
where pa.id in
(
    select b.id 
    from [mytable] b 
    where b.itemReferenceId = :itemReferenceId 
    and b.publicationId = :publicationId
    and rownum <= 1
    order by b.lastPublishedDate desc
)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply can you suggest query for my EDIT section query which is using top 1 in it.

Comment: @SIB...thanks.. I am getting wiered error, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [publication_id] and my query is populated as below
2013-01-16 09:59:04,709 DEBUG QueryTranslatorImpl - HQL: select pa from com.tridion.storage.dao.PublishAction pa where pa.id in(select pb.id from com.tridion.storage.dao.PublishAction pb where pb.tcmUri = :tcmURI and pb.publication_id = :pubID and rownum <= 1 order by pb.last_published_date desc)...please suggest what could be the reason

Comment: Are you using? `queryParams.put("publicationId", value);`
& `queryParams.put("itemReferenceId", value);`

Comment: Yes, I am using the same, please see sample code above in edit section

Comment: HI SIB, I am getting below error after fixing above issue.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.